# C# SQL Server Assembly Raise Error?

Tags: c#, sql-server, error-handling, assemblies

I have several assemblies for SQL Server 2005.

If invalid data is entered to be run by my SP function (using C#), I want to pass back an error to sql server.

For example, if someone enters something I don't want them to then I want to output something back to SQL Server prior to executing any query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Throw an exception.
Or, if you're using the SQL Context Connection, you can use SqlPipe to call 'raiserror' in SQL.